# fire a function after triggering a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can fix this :

```
function Navigation(sender) {
    var senderID = sender.id;


    var answer = confirm("do you want to save your current layout ?");
    if (answer) {
        $("#loadingImg").css("display", "block");
        $("#<%=Button1.ClientID %>").click();
         //the next line is never fired
         if (senderID == "AboutClick") { setTimeout('ShowLoadingMsg()', 3000); } 

    }    
 }
function ShowLoadingMsg() {
   window.location="About.aspx";
}

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="AboutClick" class="menu" onclick="Navigation(this);" >Navigate Click</a>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="btnSaveState_Click" style="display:none;" />
```

//Server side:

```
 protected void btnSaveState_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     SaveState();

}
```

The main problem is that this line is never fired what am i doing wrong here

Comment: the line with the comment : if (senderID == "AboutClick") { setTimeout('ShowLoadingMsg()', 3000); }

Comment: What happens in `Button1.click`?

Comment: i made an edit to the post please check

Comment: Does Button1.click send data to the server and cause a postback? If it does that might be preventing the subsequent line from executing properly.

Comment: Use `console.log(senderID)` to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `$("#<%=Button1.ClientID %>").click();` causes the entire page to reload. It won't really matter what scripts you set a timeout for after that, since the page is refreshed anyway.

You could try putting `Button1` inside an [UpdatePanel](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fbb399001%28v%3Dvs.100%29.aspx&ei=8ns3UIfpI4aWswbSsIGIBw&usg=AFQjCNHNaj70ADNDcLEKFjArGvw8r8LY-Q), or just solve the problem in another way, such as saving state and redirecting in the same method.

Comment: i can't also use ajax bcs it don't work with what i'm doing in my code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" id="AboutClick" class="menu trigger">Navigate Click</a>​
```

-

```
$(function(){
    $(".trigger").click(function(){
        var answer = confirm("do you want to save your current layout ?");
        if (answer) {
            $("#loadingImg").show();
            if (this.id == "AboutClick") { setTimeout('ShowLoadingMsg()', 3000); }
            $("#<%=Button1.ClientID %>").click();
        }  
    })       
})

function ShowLoadingMsg() {
   window.location="About.aspx";
}
```

[Demo here!](http://jsfiddle.net/tw4pS/)